# Dynamic Input in AutoCAD gives unexpected result when moving object?

Tags: cad, autocad

Suppose I have a circle with a diameter of 1000 units, located at [1000, 1000, 0] coordinate.

When I move the circle using **Command Line**, using its center point as base, and I intend to move it to [1500, 1500, 0], it **works as expected**, as can be seen in this recording:

[image: command line]

But when I repeated the same exact command with **Dynamic Input** on, the result is the circle moved to another **unexpected point** after I confirmed the value. Even though the **preview is showing the new location correctly**, the circle moved immediately after I pressed Enter, as can be seen in this recording:

[image: dynamic input]

This is repeatable and the circle always moves to that same unexpected point, so I figured some settings might be incorrectly set.
I have tried resetting AutoCAD to default setting, but the problem persist. How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not an ACAD user so can't help, but just wanted to say +1 for good question formatting, GIFs etc. It's really clear what the problem is - I hope someone can help.

Comment: Absolute positioning versus relative positioning?  I don't use dynamic entry as it bugs the crap out of me.  I would find coordinates 1500,1500 before you do you move, and see if that is where you circle is going to.  I would also find the coordinates +1500 x and +1500 y from your circles start point and see if the circle is going there.  If those are the two different spots, then you have the difference between absolute coordinates and relative.

Comment: Great question...because I happen to be experiencing the same issue and can't seem to find resources online that deal with this particular issues. Have you been able to find the solution? Thanks!